# Сохранение состояния окна PopUp после работы формы

Tags: php, javascript, html

Идея такова, имеется форма обратной связи, которая появляется поверх сайта в виде окна `PopUp`, после того, как я заполняю форму и нажимаю отправить, ее в том же файле обрабатывает `PHP` код и он должен выводить вместо формы сообщение об успешной отправке, но оно скрывает окно и если еще раз нажать кнопку на сайте для этого окна, то можно увидеть как раз это окно с сообщением об успешной отправке. Поэтому возник вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы после нажатия `submit` в форме `PopUp` окно не скрывалось, а выводилось сообщение об успешной отправке? И как потом очистить `POST` запрос, чтобы если закрыть окно и открыть его 2 раз или обновить страницу, снова появилось окно для ввода сообщения.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  PopUpHide();
});

function PopUpShow() {
  $("#popup").show();
}

function PopUpHide() {
  $("#popup").hide();
}
```

```html
<div class="b-popup" id="popup">
  <form method="POST" id="feedback-form">
    <a href="javascript:PopUpHide()"><img src="images/close.png" class="close-button"></a><br> Как к Вам обращаться:
    <input type="text" name="nameFF" required placeholder="Ваше ФИО" x-autocompletetype="name"> E-mail для связи:
    <input type="email" name="contactFF" required placeholder="Ваш E-mail" x-autocompletetype="email"> Ваше сообщение:
    <textarea name="messageFF" required rows="5"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="отправить">
  </form>
  <?
           if (isset ($_POST['messageFF'])) {
              mail ("myemail",
              "Заполнена контактная форма",
              "Имя: ".$_POST['nameFF']."\nEmail: ".$_POST['contactFF']."\nСообщение: ".$_POST['messageFF']);
              echo ('<script>document.getElementById(\'feedback-form\').innerHTML = \'<a href="javascript:PopUpHide()"><img src="images/close.png" class="close-button"></a><br><p style="color: green">Ваше сообщение получено, спасибо!</p> \'; </script>');
           }
        ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советую сделать ajax запрос.

```
$('#feedback-form').on('submit', function(e) {
     var $form = $(this);
     e.preventDefault();

     $.post('', $form.serialize())
         .done(function() {
               // тут можно открыть поверх попап с уведомлением и т.п.
         })
})
```